# J2ME: How to parse tags in a text file?

Tags: text, java-me, tags

I have a .txt file that includes:

<=txt>Hi, my name is Dana!<=txt=>
<=txt>What is your name?<=txt=>

I want to parse the text between the <=txt> element and <=txt=> element, and then show it to my j2me application on Canvas how do I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function available in the standard API's. So you either have to search for a 3rd party library, or code your own little function.

Stripping tags from a text string isn't that difficult. It could look something like this for example:

```
private String stripTags(String strIn) {
 boolean include = true;
 StringBuffer sbIn = new StringBuffer().append(strIn);
 StringBuffer sbOut = new StringBuffer();
 for (int n = 0; n < sbIn.length(); n++) {
  if (sbIn.charAt(n)=='<') include = false;
  if (include) sbOut.append(sbIn.charAt(n));
  if (sbIn.charAt(n)=='>') include = true;
 }
return sbOut.toString();
}
```

Then you can use that function in your code.

```
String stripped = stripTags("<=txt>Hi, my name is Dana! <=txt>What is your name?");
System.out.println(stripped);
```

Should output: Hi, my name is Dana! What is your name?